# How to prevent malicious injection in argument to php "exec" (webhook -> bash script)

Tags: php, bash, http-post, code-injection, webhooks

I've written a webhook to integrate into chat (slack / mattermost api).

The simplest way to get it up and running was a quick php script, which looks like this:

```
<?php
$token = $_POST["token"];
$arg = $_POST["text"];

$output = exec("./webhook_script.sh {$token} {$arg}");
```

As it stands, the script works fine, but I am worried that someone can maliciously do an http POST where the query paramter `text` (script: `$arg`) has some kind of injection attack.

Example: `http://myserver/webhook.php?token=abc&text=123;rm -rf *`

So `$arg` becomes `123; rm -rf` and the `exec` commands executes a malicious `rm -rf *`

This is similar in nature to "sql injection" which I am familiar with, but I'm not sure how to make a bash script secure...

Is it a simple matter of quoting the arguments somehow, or perhaps using a `regex` to check against the script parameters?

Comment: If I may say, this is a terrible approach for a production machine. If you really must invoke exec() with user-supplied arguments, I suggest you apply a whitelist, not a blacklist. What arguments are you expecting to receive?

Comment: the argument is an internal url. i could apply a regex to the pattern?

Comment: @Calchas or can you suggest a better way to respond to a web hook and launch a bash script. The php solution seems quick and easy, and Michael's answer below shows steps to make it secure.

Comment: It isn't secure, for one, because we have no idea how webhook_script.sh handles unexpected arguments [and right now you are letting us invoke webhook_script.sh with anything we want]. You should certainly check to see if $token and $arg are in the format you expect them to be in. It is unwise to trust data that comes from the client.

Comment: Right. I can mention that `token` is a secret token that is only known to the client. If it doesn't match then the script fails. And `text` is a url to an internal server - I should match it versus a regex beginning with `http://our.internal.server/....` and thirdly implement `escapeshellarg()` on all arguments as per Michael's answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to call [`escapeshellarg()`](http://php.net/escapeshellarg) on each shell argument before passing them to `exec()`. This wraps each argument in single quotes and escapes any single quotes that may be present, frustrating any such attacks.

```
$token = escapeshellarg($_POST["token"]);
$arg = escapeshellarg($_POST["text"]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Michael.